# OR operation of two two black and white images using PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'd like to perform an OR operation on two images using PIL/Pillow. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
def image_union(figure1, figure2):

    image1 = Image.open(figure1.visualFilename)
    image2 = Image.open(figure2.visualFilename)

    blended = Image.blend(image1, image2, .5)
    output = ImageOps.grayscale(blended)
    output.save('out-' + figure1.name + '-' + figure2.name + '.png')

    return blended
```

I'd like to OR these two images:

[image]

[image]

but the above operation returns the following, whereas I would expect the two bottom circles attached to the star to be fully black:

[image]

Comment: The bottom circles are grey because `blend()` is interpolating 50% between black and white. No sure why you're converting the output to `grayscale()` as it would be already. If the input images are color, what result do you want/expect from ORing their pixels together?

Comment: I was hoping grayscale() would change any pixel NOT white into black, making those bottom two circles black. The input images are never in color.

Comment: @LimH. you know it ;)

Comment: What does KBAI mean?

Comment: @martineau knowledge based AI - it's a popular online class offered by georgia tech. this isn't necessarily a homework question though - the entire assignment is much broader in scope, this is simply a small portion of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ImageChops.darker`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.darker) instead of `Image.blend`.

```
blended = ImageChops.darker(image1, image2)
```